# C# Writing zeros in MemoryStream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, memorystream, zero

I am using this code to save files in byte arrays in sql database and it works with little text files but when I try with, for example, word document it doesn't work:

```
public async Task<ICollection<DescriptionFile>> GetDescriptionFiles(List<IFormFile> files, Assignment assignment)
    {
        var descriptionFiles = new List<DescriptionFile>();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
            {
                using var stream = new MemoryStream();
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);

                descriptionFiles.Add(new DescriptionFile()
                {
                    Assignment = assignment,
                    Content = stream.ToArray(),
                    Name = file.FileName,
                    ContentType = file.ContentType,
                });
            }
        }

        return descriptionFiles;
    }
```

For some reason the value of `Content` is this : `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`

Why are all these 0s appearing?

Comment: Read the bytes of the src files, compare what is wrong, set breakpoints etc

Comment: @Charles All the 0s are wrong. Maybe the MemoryStream starts writing from different position? Do I have to flush it?

Comment: What do the raw files look like?

Comment: @GeorgiKolev did you try to store the files in separate Buffers / MemoryStreams. I would do that first, then see if they have trailing zeroes or something, then it should also be easy to trim the zeros and merge the parts

Comment: @Charles What do you mean separate buffers? In every iteration of the foreach loop, it creates a new instance of MemoryStream. So each file is written in new buffer, I think? Can you specify?

Comment: How are you writing the content to a single `IFormFile` which you get passed in to this function? The behavior looks like when people implment their own tcp copying and have big buffers but dont remember to use the returned value of `Read(...)` to tell if all bytes where read out before returning the buffer array.

Comment: @GeorgiKolev Is this a webapp? Can you try to read the request body completely first, without writing to files etc. Maybe you just get a partial request.

Comment: Now I found out it also works with images but not with .docx, .pdf, etc.

Comment: @Charles yes, it's a web app. I am sure that the files I am getting are OK because they are on my PC.

Comment: If you open the files with a hex editor and compare the bytes side by side, are the 0000 inserted into the normal file bytes or are they replacing the normal file bytes?